# App stops responding while getting user profile from Google

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I tried to use Google .NET API to get verified user email, but app stops responding in line I marked with ****. The first time I run it opens browser and asks for my GMAIL, after selecting gmail it says now you can close browser window, but my desktop app will stop responding. Next time I run app it just stops responding unless I delete `Google.Apis.Auth` folder from `AppData\Roaming` :

```
        private async Task VerifyEmail()
        {
            UserCredential credential;
            credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                new ClientSecrets
                {
                    ClientId = "xxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com",
                    ClientSecret = "xxxx-xxxxx"
                },
                new[] { Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.Oauth2Service.Scope.UserinfoEmail },
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore("My.DataStore")
                );

            var initializer =
        new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            HttpClientInitializer = credential,
            ApplicationName = "My App",
        };
            var oauthSerivce = new Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2.Oauth2Service(initializer);

            // app stops responding here **** :
            var userInfo = await oauthSerivce.Userinfo.Get().ExecuteAsync();
            MessageBox.Show(userInfo.Email);
        }
```

Comment: "GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.Authorize **Async** " ... await it.

Comment: @Fildor it has .Result, same as await.

Comment: _"it has .Result, same as await"_ - LOL. Wait until @StevenCleary sees this.

Comment: @AVEbrahimi no it's not the same. Your code is deadlocking because your not `await`ing. Add an await at the right point(s) and it should work as expected.

Comment: added await (in question above too), still deadlock. :|

Comment: changed var userInfo = await oauthSerivce.Userinfo.Get().ExecuteAsync(); to var userInfo = oauthSerivce.Userinfo.Get().ExecuteAsync().Result;
now it works, but I don't understand it, would you please help @Fildor

Comment: hmm, interesting... and strange. Did you try using `.ConfigureAwait(false)` ?

Comment: I'd imagine that your not `await`ing up the chain. What calls `VerifyEmail` is this `async` and what about it's parent, and it's parent? All async methods need to be called async or you need to offload this work to a thread pool thread

Comment: @Liam all correct, thanks, now working using await. Please add your last comment as answer so other people use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the content of this question is in the comments, so I've summarised below:

> it has `.Result`, same as await.

`.Result` isn't the same as `await`. `await` marks the call as `async` and tells .Net to run this in an asynchronous context, without blocking. `.Result` blocks the thread and tries to obtain the result. You should (mostly) never block on async code like this, check out Stephen Cleary's blog [Don't Block on Async Code](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

> added await (in question above too), still deadlock. :|

`async` code needs to be called in an `async` context. So you must make all the parent methods async as well. [You can use a thread pool thread to get around this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343594/how-to-call-asynchronous-method-from-synchronous-method-in-c). But the best solutions is to make all your previous method calls `async`. This does mean than `async` tends o spread though your code base but that's the nature of the beast.